# Django : cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

i'm learning django and Python. I have a problem with a form.

the error is "TypeError at /My_app" and "cannot unpack non-iterable int object"

this is my views :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from datetime import datetime

from Qualite.forms import NCForm
from Qualite.models import NC, Nc_type, Poste

def view_accueil(request):

    form = NCForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        newNc = NC()
        newNc.idaffaire = form.cleaned_data['idaffaire']
        newNc.idnc = form.cleaned_data['idnc']
        newNc.idof = form.cleaned_data['idof']
        newNc.idposte = form.cleaned_data['idposte']
        newNc.idrepere = form.cleaned_data['idrepere']
        newNc.iquantite = form.cleaned_data['iquantite']
        newNc.save()

    return render(request, 'Qualite/accueil.html', locals())
```

my forms :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Nc_type, NC, Poste

class NCForm(forms.Form):

    #choices = NC.objects.values_list('id', 'idaffaire')
    ncs = NC.objects.values_list('idaffaire', flat = True)

    idaffaire = forms.ChoiceField(choices = (ncs))
    idof = forms.CharField()
    idrepere = forms.CharField()
    idposte = forms.CharField()
    idnc = forms.CharField()
    quantite = forms.CharField()
```

and my model

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Nc_type(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom

class Poste(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom


class NC(models.Model):
    idaffaire = models.CharField(max_length=4, db_column='idAffaire')
    idof = models.IntegerField(db_column='idOf')
    idposte = models.ForeignKey('Poste', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column="idPoste", default=1)
    idrepere = models.IntegerField(db_column='idRepere')
    idnc = models.ForeignKey(Nc_type, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idNc_type', default=1)
    quantite = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    dateajout = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_column='dateAjout')
```

and the template:

```
<h1>Ajout d'une NC</h1>

<form action="{% url "accueil" %}" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

is it someone to help me to understand the problem. I searched solution on the web but no way.

Comment: Why don't you use a `ModelForm` such that most of the boilerplate code can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a query like:

```
ncs = NC.objects.values_list('idaffaire', flat=True)
```

will result in `ncs` being an interable of `int` objects. But the `choices` of a `ChoiceField` require a list of *2-tuples* with the key as first item of these 2-tuples, and the label as second item of the 2-tuples.

Nevertheless, using a query at the class level is *not* a good idea at all. It means that the query will be performed with the class is loaded. This means that if you later add an extra `NC` object, the form will not offer this as a new choice.

I would also advise to make use of a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead, since that will remove a lot of boilerplate code, especially since `idposte` for example needs to use a valid value for the `Poste` object, and here your form can not validate that.

You can then implement the form as:

```
from django import forms
from .models import NC

class NCForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NC
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then in your `views.py`, you can use this form with:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def view_accueil(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NCForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-a-view')
    else:
        form = NCForm()
    return render(request, 'Qualite/accueil.html', {'form': form})
```

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
>   [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
>   to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>   This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
>   browser.

Comment: @ROGGYQUENTIN: You need to specify the name of a view instead of `'name-of-view'`. This is the name of the view to where you want to redirect. So if you have for example a `url('some/url', some_view, name='name_of_my_view')`, you can `redirect('name_of_my_view')`.